# Multiple Slideshow activity

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I've made a simple activity with 6 `ViewFlippers`. Each `ViewFlipper` has 4 images that has a fade in, fade out animation. When I tried it on my device, it runs fine. But when I try it on my other devices, it doesn't show any animation. The settings for the animation for the other phones is the same with my phone, having animations at 1x. This might be a limitation on the memory capacity of the other devices so my question is, is there any thing more simpler and lighter that can support 6 or more slide-like views?

Comment: have you got any error.

Comment: There is no error. It's just that the animation does not work on my other devices compared to the one I'm using now.